# postgis/postgres ST_Distance and GROUP BY

Tags: postgis, postgresql, error, syntax

Trying to find the nearest road to a postcode point and order the results by distance.  The roads are named according to UK convention so A606 etc and there are multiple entries for many road numbers (different bits of A606 may occur 5 or 6 times with differing OID).

So far:

```
SELECT MIN(ST_Distance(geom1, geom2):: NUMERIC, 2), q.postcode, a.number AS "a_road"
FROM env.a_road, env.postcode q, pdetails.p
WHERE q."postcode" = p."PostCode"
GROUP BY a.number
ORDER BY ST_Distance(geom1, geom2) ASC;
```

I know this is not correct with respect to the aggregate function and GROUP BY clause but how to get around it?

I want to return a table as `|postcode|a_road|distance_m`
with only one postcode entry, one nearest road and one distance to that nearest road.

My closest attempt has been this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (q.postcode)q.postcode, a.number, ROUND(ST_Distance(q.geom, a.geom)::NUMERIC, 2) as distance_m
FROM env.a_road, env.postcode q, pdetails.p
WHERE q.postcode = p.Postcode
ORDER BY q.postcode, ST_Distance(q.geom, a.geom) ASC;
```

Returns the right results but I can't sort by distance because of that same initial problem of having q.postcode in the GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way. I suggest a) you join on st_dwithin() (or otherwise use that function), because it will make use of spatial indexes and reduce the size of the computation, and b) do the intensive query first, then worry about joining the pdetails table.

Also, I assume your geometries are in some sort of projected units (otherwise your distances will be in degrees...).

```
SELECT postcode,a_road, distance_m FROM
    (SELECT q.postcode, a.number as a_road, ROUND(ST_Distance(q.geom, a.geom)::NUMERIC, 2) as distance_m, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY q.postcode,a.number ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(a.geom,q.geom)) as row_number
        FROM env.a_road a
        INNER JOIN env.postcode q ON
        ST_DWITHIN(a.geom,q,geom,5000) -- use a sensible distance to restrict the result set without losing records 
    ) a
    INNER JOIN pdetails p ON p."PostCode" = a.postcode
    WHERE a.row_number = 1;
```

Apologies for any typos - if you'd posted table structure and some sample records I could have tested it!